# Generate Group/Segment Identity with CTEs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

The problem is having to generate a serial GroupID in column A(Segment) which starts to identify rows from A till the next C of column B(Indicator) as a segment. Column B is an indicator of Segment start(A) and Segment end (C).. anything in between (B or X) should be marked with a segment ID including the rows with A and C. Hope it is clear enough.

[File as received](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/35/beforen.png/)

[Processed file with generated Group/Segment identity](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/689/afterqf.png/)

I need suggestions which will the best solution to the problem. I have a .Net loop doing this slowly but am experimenting with CTEs. Please help.

Comment: Whatever the method will be, I'd say that you _must_ have a column that you can _order_ the data by. Is there no ID column?

Comment: There is no guaranteed mapping from physical to logical ordering. If you don't have an ordering column in the source data, you're going to need to pre-process row-by-row.

Comment: ...by reading the file through some other process (e.g. C# or anything that can open and read a file really) and understanding which row is first, second, etc. Once SQL Server has the data in a table or data source, it is by definition an unordered set of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has an Id column, and your table is called [Stuff], then this works:

```
-- Set the segment values for rows where Indicator = 'A'
update [Stuff]
    set Segment = s.row
from
    (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) as Row, Id 
    from [Stuff] where Indicator = 'A' ) s
where
    s.Id = [Stuff].Id

-- Update the other rows
update [Stuff]
set Segment = (
    select top 1 Segment from [Stuff] s1 
    where s1.Segment is not null and s1.Id <= [Stuff].Id 
    order by Id desc
)

update [Stuff] set Segment = -1 where Indicator = '#'
update [Stuff] set Segment = 0 where Indicator = '##'
```

Comment: I can certainly have an ID column to indicate the row number and do something like what Phil has done. With an added ID column I am trying to see if this can be done with a CTE which wouldn't need any table updates and locks and stuff.. Please let me know if you guys can think of an efficient technique (if possible with CTEs).